# How do I revert edits on my question?

Tags: support, editing

I asked this question [How do the advantages of a flipped classroom overcome timing issues?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/61010/what-are-the-advantages-of-a-flipped-classroom) and got some good answers, focussed on my concerns. The title has now been edited to something that is too general. That is, it will encourage shopping lists of advantages instead of 'what are the advantages that offset my concerns'. As the asker, I was notified of the edits, but I don't seem to have an option to reject them and I thought there was a veto power for the asker.

I will end up simply editing the title again to pick up the concerns of the editor but to also focus on the aspect I wan answered. But it would be good if someone could point to how I should have reverted the title.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general: to revert an edit on your own post, you can click on the "Edited" link to get to the revision history. In the revision history, for every edit except the most recent one, there is a "rollback" option to revert the post to that particular version.

> As the asker, I was notified of the edits, but I don't seem to have an option to reject them and I thought there was a veto power for the asker.

If an edit is suggested, you see the notification, and you reject the edit before it is approved, then the edit will not be applied. If the edit is made by a high-rep user and doesn't need to be reviewed, or if it is reviewed and approved before you reject it, then it'll be applied.

The system doesn't wait for the original author to get around to explicitly approving or rejecting every edit before applying the edit. Stack Exchange is [big on community editing](https://academia.stackexchange.com/help/editing).

But as the author, you can always revert an edit or re-edit the post to make it even better  (just refrain from edit wars, please!)

> I will end up simply editing the title again to pick up the concerns of the editor but to also focus on the aspect I wan answered.

In this instance, that seems like a great way to handle it. The new title is more focused (i.e. better) than either previous version.